# How to set particular div at some height in DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a input Tag which I am getting by using this

```
this.el.dom
```

My Tag :

```
<input type="text" size="24" autocomplete="off" id="SomeID" name="undefined" class="SomeClass" style="width: 28px;" title="">
```

I have a div which is something like this

```
<div id="myDiv" style="background-color: rgb(44, 141, 194); color: white; padding: 5px; height: 50px; width: 300px; border-style: solid;"></mydiv>
```

I wanted `mydiv` to display below `110px`. Any idea how can I display `myDiv` below `110px` of input.

Comment: you want to display 110px below your input tag ?

Comment: add margin to myDiv

Comment: `<mydiv ...` is not a valid HTML tag! Use `<div id="myDiv" ..></div>`

Comment: first of all i would like to say is `<mydiv>` is not a valid tag use `<div>` instead of '<mydiv>' and you can use `margin-top:110px;` to get display below 110px.

Answer (score 0):

Use standard HTML tags Change `<mydiv>` to `<div>`

```
<div id="myDiv" style="background-color: rgb(44, 141, 194); color: white; padding: 5px; height: 50px; width: 300px; border-style: solid;">    </div>
```

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.marginTop = "110px";
```